Indexing using a variable in R
I am trying to create a for loop which will find me the maximum year of deaths
I tried the following code:
result <- c()
years <- c("2020", "2021", "2022")
i <- 1
for (year in years){
     result[i] <- data$age[which.max(data$year)]
     i <- i + 1
}

However, this gave me NULL as the result vector.

What is data$age?

For a single maximum: data = data.frame(years = c("2020", "2021", "2022"), deaths = c(146, 148, 158)); with(data, years[which.max(deaths)])

Are you mixing up death and age? Your question is not reproducible.

Sorry all, I didn't understand the problem and my duplicate does not solve the problem.

@Friede I want to find the age bracket which has the maximum deaths for each year 2020, 2021 and 2022. Instead of repeating the code:
data$age[which.max(data$"2020")]
three times and just changing the 2020 to 2021 and 2022 each time, I want to write a loop which can loop through the years.

data$"2020" is not valid R-syntax. Please (edit)(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78883843/indexing-using-a-variable-in-r?noredirect=1#comment139095094_78883843) your question and add data as text in. Use the/some output of  dput(data). We then vote to re-open your question and will answer it.

One way to solve your problem:
tapply(data$age, data$year, max)


The problem is your code is with this code which.max(data$year)
data$year, will return the whole year column, which means which.max(data$year) will always return the same value for each loop iteration, So instead use a different approach.
In the loop, filter the data for the current year, then use the which.max method to find the max-age.
for (year in years){
     data_f <- data[data$year == year, ] # filtering the data
     result[i] <- data_f$age[which.max(data_f$age)] # Findong the max age for current year
     i <- i + 1
}



I get this error code when trying the above code:
Error in male_age_sex[male_age_sex$year == year, ]:
! Can't subset rows with male_age_sex$year == year.
✖ Logical subscript male_age_sex$year == year must be size 1 or 9, not 0.
Backtrace:

male_age_sex[male_age_sex$year == year, ]
vctrs (local) <fn>()
vctrs:::stop_indicator_size(...)

Is it because of the way my columns are named? (male_age_sex is the data name)
